# Is adding a time dummy the same as estimating by within-time fixed effects?

Tags: categorical-data, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Is it the same to estimate the time fixed effect by the within estimator and by simply adding time dummies in my regression equation? Why would that be the case mathematically?

---

**edit**

$$\text{Y}_{ist}=\gamma_s+TFE+\sum^m_{\tau=0}\delta_{-\tau}\text{D}_{s,t-\tau}+\sum^q_{\tau=1}\delta_{+\tau}\text{D}_{s,t+\tau}+\text{X}'_{ist}\beta+\varepsilon_{ist} \tag1$$

Where TFE mean time fixed effect, I can estimate this using within estimation in R or Stata, my question is that does estimate equation (1) using within estimator same as estimate the following equation (2)

$$\text{Y}_{ist}=\gamma_s+\text{time dummies}+\sum^m_{\tau=0}\delta_{-\tau}\text{D}_{s,t-\tau}+\sum^q_{\tau=1}\delta_{+\tau}\text{D}_{s,t+\tau}+\text{X}'_{ist}\beta+\varepsilon_{ist} \tag2$$

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi , I rewrite my question, hope it works this time

Comment: In light of the upvoted & accepted answer, I think this must be clear enough. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the "within transformation" only works for a single fixed effect, but the [method of alternating projections](https://www.frisch.uio.no/english/publications/?pubid=888) is supposed to be equivalent to FWL projection ([though I've had trouble getting it to work in practice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268960/method-of-alternating-projections-for-linear-fixed-effects-models)).

Mathematically, the reason time fixed effects are equivalent to time dummies is that time fixed effects ARE time dummies.  Only the method of estimating the model relies on projection, rather than directly solving for all of the coefs.

It is a simple application of the [FWL theorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem).

Comment: thank you @generic_user for the answer and the references. Now I understand that fixed effect does indeed is dummies, and when you use within estimation, the coefficients of the dummies will be wiped out by 'demean',while the estimation by adding dummies will keep the coefficients. right?

Comment: Right. (There is a character minimum in comments)